# Embedding ListView in another View

Tags: android, listview

How can I embed my listview in a layout that I have already created? For example in `my_layout.xml` I have something like:

```
<linear layout>
<textview>
<*my list view goes here*>
<linear layout>
```

I created a List Activity like so:

```
public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your xml my_layout.xml:

```
<linear layout>
<textview>
      <ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"                 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
       </ListView>
<linear layout>
```

and your java file:

```
public class HelloListView extends Activity { // not use ListActivity

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout); 
    ListView lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list); 
    // make something for List adapter
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));


    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  }
```

}

hope helping you

Comment: Thanks @monkey. Your answer looks correct, however, I get a compile error where it can't find `setListAdapter(...)`. Should this be `lv.setAdapter(...)`? If so, how is this implemented? Thanks!